# Help rearranging algebraic expression?!

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, factoring

In the following relationship x and $\delta_S$ are unknowns:

$$\delta_f = \delta_S-(\delta_S-\delta_o)\exp\left[-(1+mx)\frac{It}{V}\right]$$

I need to solve for x and have the following relationship for $\delta_S$:

$$\delta_S =\frac{\delta_{in}+mx\delta^*}{1+mx}$$

Therefore: $$\delta_f = \bigg(\frac{(\delta_{in}+mx\delta^*)}{(1+mx)}\bigg)-\bigg(\frac{(\delta_{in}+mx\delta^*)}{(1+mx)}-\delta_i\bigg)\exp\bigg[-(1+mx)\frac{It}{V}\bigg]$$

Honestly I have no idea where to begin isolating x once I start taking the natural log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot isolate $x$ and you will need some numerical method.

If I had to do it, I would define $y=(1+mx)$ to make 
$$\delta_f = \delta_S-(\delta_S-\delta_o)\exp\left[-y\frac{It}{V}\right]$$
$$\delta_S =\frac{\delta_{in}+mx\delta^*}{1+mx}=\frac{\delta_{in}-\delta^*+y\delta^*}{y}=\delta^*+\frac{\delta_{in}-\delta^*}y$$ Use Newton method.

In fact, I suppose that there could be an "explicit" solution in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$ in the paper).